# How can I build this circuit using a transformer core?

Tags: circuitikz, tikz-cd, circuits

I need to recreate this circuit using LaTeX:

[image]

I already have the right side circuit but still don't know how to add the transformer (left part), I checked the circuitikz manual but keep getting errors.

I'd be so thankful if someone could help me out with a code for this. **Thanks in advance**

Comment: What is your current code? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Please add a minimal working example (MWE) to your question.

Comment: i wasn't even using the transformer core, just set do circuits next to each other but that not what i needed, when tried to add the actual transformer it got messed up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following shows how to place the `transformer core` node from `circuitikz`.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw
    node[transformer core](t){}
    (t.A1)
      to[short]
    ++(-1,0) coordinate(tmp)
      to[battery1]
    (tmp|-t.A2)
      to[short]
    (t.A2)
    (t.B1)
      to[R=$R_1$]
    ++(2.4,0) coordinate(tmp)
      to[L=$L_1$]
    (tmp|-t.B2)
      to[C=$C_1$]
    (t.B2)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice!!! thank you so so much :)

Comment: do you know how can i label both the transformers? i forgot to add it to the drawing

Comment: @ronny, there are quite a bunch of example in the manual, starting from page 113, under "Double bipoles (transformers)": https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#subsection.4.18